# What is the rule for htaccess rewrite on XAMMP?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

So far after googling for the answer for hours I come across tones of answers, and I came to the conclusion that is very different in each case that I need to show you guys my case in order to get help:

The rule does not work on either localhost or online so that I am sure is something wrong with the rule and not with XAMMP. Cause I also edited the httpd.conf files as mentioned in many answers.

So here is my file directory:

http://localhost/WEBSHOP/shopaholic.php
http://localhost/WEBSHOP/rewrite.htaccess

and here is the code of the rewrite.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /WEBSHOP/
 RewriteRule ^shopaholic$ /shopaholic.php/
</IfModule>
```

I have also tried, which did not help
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.so>`
And obviously I just want to get rid of the .php extension.

Comment: The file name is `.htaccess`, not `rewrite.htaccess`? Because, you can't change the name...

Comment: She can, actually. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#accessfilename

Comment: changing the name to .htaccess it worked. Thank´s